# In common lisp, what is the best way to print to multiple consoles?

Tags: common-lisp

I want multiple consoles running under the same process. I want to do:

```
(format console1 "foo") ;prints to iterm tab1
(format console2 "bar") ;prints to iterm tab2
(format t "baz") ;prints to slime repl
```

I also want to be able to read from all 3 streams. Slime will keep a standard REPL, but I want to build custom REPLs for the 2 terms

Answer (score 5):

### Output

Use [`MAKE-BROADCAST-STREAM`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_bro.htm). For example:

```
(setf *standard-output*
  (make-broadcast-stream *standard-output*
                         (open #P"/tmp/log.out" :direction :output)))
```

This will redirect all the standard output to a broadcast stream composed of the current `*standard-output*` and a new stream, writing in a file. If you write commands after this redirection, you should be able to observe the file being written.
Note also that without any argument `(make-broadcast-stream)` is the way you typically build a sink stream, a little bit like `/dev/null`.

### Input

Reading from multiple streams is different. How do you decide which one should be get the priority if they all emit input simultaneously? Do you need separate threads that read input in parallel and push in a synchronized way into a single stream?